# Whats the exception there?

Tags: android, shapes

please anyone can help  me ?  i'm using shape in android to customize
 edit box and i have this error :( this error show on creat method and
 try to fix it but no result
 i call it Like this :  android:background="@drawable/shape"
 in google i haven't any result

```
> 
>      10-24 22:02:22.390  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
>         10-24 22:02:22.590  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 225K, 37% free 9792K/15363K, paused
> 42ms, total 43ms
>         10-24 22:02:22.710  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 34.103MB for 16384016-byte
> allocation
>         10-24 22:02:22.770  11271-11274/info.androidhive.slidingmenu D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 12K, 18% free 25779K/31431K, paused
> 20ms+3ms, total 59ms
>         10-24 22:02:23.060  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 18% free 25780K/31431K, paused
> 24ms, total 24ms
>         10-24 22:02:23.060  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Forcing collection of SoftReferences for
> 36864016-byte allocation
>         10-24 22:02:23.110  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 19% free 25770K/31431K, paused
> 58ms, total 58ms
>         10-24 22:02:23.110  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu E/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Out of memory on a 36864016-byte allocation.
>         10-24 22:02:23.120  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
>         10-24 22:02:23.120  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40ee16a0
> self=0x40de30b8
>         10-24 22:02:23.120  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ | sysTid=11271 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps
> handle=1075402832
>         10-24 22:02:23.120  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=80 stm=25 core=1
>         10-24 22:02:23.120  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native
> Method)
>         10-24 22:02:23.120  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at
> android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:636)
>         10-24 22:02:23.120  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at
> android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:484)
>         10-24 22:02:23.130  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at
> android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:813)
>         10-24 22:02:23.130  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at
> android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2822)
>         10-24 22:02:23.130  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at
> android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
>         10-24 22:02:23.130  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3419)
>         10-24 22:02:23.130  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:432)
>         10-24 22:02:23.130  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at
> android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:176)
>         10-24 22:02:23.130  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at
> android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:172)
>         10-24 22:02:23.130  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native
> Method)
>         10-24 22:02:23.130  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at
> java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
>         10-24 22:02:23.130  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:593)
>         10-24 22:02:23.150  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at
> com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
>         10-24 22:02:23.150  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:666)
>         10-24 22:02:23.150  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
>         10-24 22:02:23.150  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:467)
>         10-24 22:02:23.150  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>         10-24 22:02:23.150  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
>         10-24 22:02:23.150  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at
> com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:318)
>         10-24 22:02:23.150  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1925)
>         10-24 22:02:23.150  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at
> info.androidhive.slidingmenu.Login.onCreate(Login.java:11)
>         10-24 22:02:23.150  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5203)
>         10-24 22:02:23.150  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
>         10-24 22:02:23.150  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078)
>         10-24 22:02:23.150  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
>         10-24 22:02:23.150  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
>         10-24 22:02:23.160  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
>         10-24 22:02:23.160  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>         10-24 22:02:23.160  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>         10-24 22:02:23.160  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
>         10-24 22:02:23.160  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>         10-24 22:02:23.160  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>         10-24 22:02:23.160  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
>         10-24 22:02:23.160  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
>         10-24 22:02:23.160  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>         10-24 22:02:23.160  11271-11271/info.androidhive.slidingmenu I/dalvikvm﹕ [ 10-24 22:02:23.160 11271:11271 F/libc     ]
>             Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 11271 (ive.slidingmenu)
```

Comment: "Out of memory" seems to be the important part

Comment: You are decoding an asset that is to large to be shown

Answer (score 1):

This is happening due to Bitmap being too large to decode. You can follow below procedure too handle this.

1. Sample the image to nearest sampling value to make bitmap become memory efficient.
2. After decoding you can scale it up to fit your desired size.

Sample code:

```
      // for smpling purpose
       backImage =decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),R.drawable.back, width, height);

      // For bringing it back to desired size

     backImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(backImage, width, height, false);
```